Error authenticating with JWT config due to: user hasn't approved this consumer
I'm using the following command in Gitlab to authorize with a sandbox:
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid <ClientId> --jwtkeyfile .gitlab/common/server.key --username <userName> --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setalias Dummy

However, it is throwing an error:
ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: Error authenticating with JWT config due to: user hasn't approved this consumer
Few things I would like to mention:

I didn't face this issue until recently when I refreshed a sandbox.
Client ID is good, pre-authorization for admin is enabled, and the user is the admin.
Connected app access is also there.
Most probably, Salesforce changed something on the Connected App, which is why it's not working. Any idea, anyone? Thanks.


do you use clientId for the Connected app from the same Sandbox or Production?

from the sandbox
